# CSS - Height: 100% vs min-height: 100%;

Tags: height, css

So in my code I have a sticky footer. And the sticky footer has the #wrap container with a `min-height` of `100%`. But with `min-height` you can't use `height:100%` on objects inside the wrap div.

So I add `height:100%` but it messes with the layout by making the footer roll over the content in the wrap div when window height is too small.

Anyone have fixes for this?

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfooter"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    color: #FFF;
    background-image:url('../images/black_denim.png');
}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -200px;
    position: relative;
}
#topBanner{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.clearfooter {
    height: 200px;
    clear: both;
}
/* footer */
#footer { 
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: I also know that you could do `position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;` to get the effect, however, since it is absolute the footer will act like content still isn't there if it is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is a sticky footer that doesn't cover up any of the body's content then just give the footer a fixed position and give the bottom of the body padding equal to the footers height.

```
body{ 
    padding-bottom:200px;
}

#footer { 
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

EDIT:

if your concern is that on very small screens the fixed footer covers up most of the screen then there is no workaround for this except for maybe hiding the footer dynamically using css media queries or javascript.

many mobile browsers do not support fixed positions precisely because of the issue of them covering large portions of the screen.

Comment: That won't work because you can still make the window small enough to where it will cover it up.

Comment: Even with the edit of `fixed` it doesn't work. You aren't understanding my issue. The code I posted works just fine at making the footer stop before it goes over any content. However, the code doesn't allow for `height:100%;` inside of the wrap because of the `min-height:100%;`. BUT the code doesn't work without the `min-height` which is my issue.

Comment: You're right, I must not understand the issue. If you could post a link to a more complete example with content then I might be of better use.